# Accessing my profile on different ps4 consoles

Tags: ps4

Can I access my psn account on 2 different consoles? We are getting a second ps4. I want to be able to log into my profile on the new console and continue my online gaming. Then if the kids are using the new console with their own profiles I want to be able to log into my account on the old console and pick up where I left off. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can log in to your account on another console, you will be able to download everything you bought from the PS Store again. As for copying files from another console, you can do it by connecting two consoles with a LAN cable and select:

> Settings -> System -> Transfer Data from Another PS4.

If you had more doubts about data portability then [this website](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/transfer.html) should help you. Below is information about which data you can transfer.

> You can transfer data saved on your current PS4™ system storage to a new PS4™ system.
>   Transferring data to your new PS4™ system initializes it, so you should transfer data before you begin using your new system. After the transfer, data also remains on your current PS4™ system.
>
> You can transfer these types of data:
>
> - All Users and Their Settings
> - Either your current PS4™ system or the new PS4™ system can be registered as your primary PS4™ system.
> - Games and Saved Data
> - Screenshots and Video Clips

*Source: [Transfer Data from Another PS4](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/ps4/settings/transfer.html)*

Comment: It should be noted that only one PS4 at a time can be primary, thus auto-cloud save uploads and other features restricted to the primary PS4 only work on that PS4 (you can manually access the cloud saves from any console, of course).